# How to manage the CRS of OpenLayers plugin in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am working with OpenLayers plugin in QGIS 1.8 but I am not sure on how should I manage the CRS.

The default CRS for Google/Bing layers is WGS84/Pseudo Mercator (EPGS:3857) but I am not sure on the CRS of the new layer I want to work on.

Answer (score 3):

For the Openlayers plugin, the **Project** CRS **must** be in EPSG:3857.

Your other layers can have different **Layer** CRS, if you have enabled `On-the-fly-reprojection`.

BTW, current version of QGIS is 2.4, and the openlayers plugin does not support older versions anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You should create new custom CRS and assign it to your layer(s). This quick and dirty approach worked for me after reading all the posts arround here. I use QGIS 2.8.1 and metric system, as I live in Central Europe:

- import Open Layer (in my case, Google Hybrid)
- import your data (in my case, our Municipality Border)
- right click on your data layer and choose "Set Layer CRS"
- Choose "Automatic Coordinate System" - this should bring your data near to desired position (in my case, 470m too much east and 370m too much south)
- Measure your x and y difference between specific point on Open Layer and that same point on your layer
- Go to Settings, Custom CRS
- Click + sign to add new Custom CRS and give it a name
- Copy parameters from Suggested "Automatc Coordinate system" to new one and alter last digits in +x_0=... and +y_0=... section with values you measure as difference in x and y direction before.
- Click OK to save it and right click on your Layer again - choose "Set Layer CRS".
- First choose previous CRS and click OK, then your new CRS and click OK.
- Your Data should align with Open Layer, otherwise experiment with settings a little more.

Maybe picture is more informative, so I attached one. Hope my approach will work for you as well.

[image]